# Какое слово тут является сказуемым?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, члены-предложения

Самая глубокая река в мире это Конго.

"это река" или "самая глубокая"?

Comment: Конго?.........

Comment: По моему " Конго " тут подлежащее . Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Мы ведь говорим не о том, какая Конго река, а о том, какая река является самой глубокой

Comment: То есть так " Это Конго " сказуемое , " река " подлежащее ?

Comment: я правильно думаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Самая глубокая река в мире это Конго.**

1. Странное предложение, **тире  перед связкой «это» нет**, никто предложение не исправляет, никто и ничего про тире не говорит.

А если тире нет, то нет и связки, но есть **инверсия** подлежащего и сказуемого. И тогда сказуемым будет «самая глубокая река в мире», а слово «это» можно считать просто указательным местоимением.

2. Тире можно поставить, и тогда это будет **тождество:**
   ***Самая глубокая река в мире – это Конго*** (это информация о самых глубоких реках). ***Конго – это самая глубокая река в мире*** (это описание реки Конго).

В тождестве на первом месте стоит подлежащее, а на втором месте сказуемое. При изменении позиции функция слов тоже меняется.

3. Таким образом, выбор варианта зависит от контекста, от структуры предложения,  и вариант без тире тоже возможен, например:

***Самая глубокая река в мире это КОнго, которая протекает в Африке.*** https://kipmu-ru.turbopages.org/kipmu.ru/s/samye-glubokie-reki-v-mire/
Сравнить: *Самая глубокая в мире река КОнго, которая протекает в Африке*.

Мы видим, что в в СПП не делается пауза в главном предложении,  поэтому тире не ставится. Также: *Самая глубокая  в мире река Конго, а  река Янцзы занимает второе место.*

Answer (score 1):

Сказуемое, выраженное существительным, здесь "Конго". Такую конструкцию легко отличить по наличию слова "это".

Примеры с "грамоты":

> Париж – это столица Франции; Понять – значит простить; Все прошедшее, настоящее, будущее – это мы, а не слепая сила стихий

[Источник](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172)